# Mongo to php date conversion

Tags: php

In mongo collection, date is `"date" : ISODate("2013-01-20T18:30:00.000Z")`
but when I convert it to readable format using `date('jS M, Y',$dataArr["date"]->sec)`, it shows me `21st Jan, 2013`.

I am not able get the reason for change in date.Thanks in advance.

Comment: `echo date("d M, Y",strtotime($dataArr["date"]));`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mongo date are saved in UTC timezone, in order to have the correct date you have you can either add your timezone to the `$date->sec` timestamp or simply use  `MongoDate` to return a `DateTime` object and then format it:

`$dataArr["date"]->toDateTime()->format('jS M, Y')`